# how to update without reloading page using ajax in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

this is the datatable , im updating sort direct from table

```
<tbody>
                      @if($data->count())
                      @foreach ( $data as $category)
                      <tr id="tr_{{ $category->id }}">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" id="" class="sub_chk" name="" value="" data-id="{{ $category->id }}"></td>
                        <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
                        <form  id="updatesortorder"
                        action="">
                        <!-- {{ url('/statesort-update',$category->id) }} -->
                          @csrf
                            <td >
                              <input type="hidden" id="cat_id" value="{{ $category->id }}">
                            <input type="number" id="sort" name="sort"  min="1" max="12"  value="{{ $category->sort }}">
                            <button type="submit" style="margin-top:00px; margin-bottom:03px; padding: 10px;padding-bottom:0px; padding-top:0px;"  class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                            </td>
                          </form>
                        <td>{{ $category->state }}</td>
                        <td>
                          <input style="" data-id="{{$category->id}}" class="toggle-class" type="checkbox" data-onstyle="success"
                          data-offstyle="danger"  data-height="25px" data-width="85px" data-size="small" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="Deactive" {{ $category->status ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <a href="{{ url('/state-edit',$category->id) }}" style="color: blue;"><i class='fas fa-edit' style='font-size:15px;color:green'></i></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                          <a href="{{ url('/state-delete',$category->id) }}" style="color: red;" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure!! you want to Delete {{ $category->state }} ?')"><i class='fas fa-trash-alt' style='font-size:15px;color:red'></i></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                      @endif
                    </tbody>
```

script for update sort order

```
<!-- ------------sortorder------------ -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Update Data

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('#updatesortorder').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            // var url = "{{url('/statesort-update',$category->id)}}";
            var sort = $("#sort").val();
              var id = $("#cat_id").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                // alert("hello");
                url: "/statesort-update/"+id,
               dataType:"Json",
               data: sort,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    // table.ajax.reload();
                    alert("hello");
                },
                error:function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>
```

**controller**

```
public function sortupdate(Request $request, $id){
           

    
            $profile = State::find($id);
            if($profile){
            $profile->sort = $request->input('sort');
            $profile->save();


            return response()->json(['success'=>'Sort change successfully.']);
        }else{
            return response()->json(['fail'=>'Error.']);
        }
        }
```

it is showing success when i click on save button but gives null value.

i have tried everything i know but not getting the result
and there are 3 entries when i click on 1st entry ajax works ,it show succes with null value
and when i click on other 2 entries it directly reloads the page and nothing is shown in the console.

```
Route::post('/statesort-update/{id}',[App\Http\Controllers\StateController::class,'sortupdate'])->name('sortupdate')->middleware('adminLoggedIn')
```

Comment: Id must be unique in HTML `id="id" id="sort"`, and also check your network call in developer console what was the request and response.

Comment: i have checked the console in response it shows success but in request it shows nothing and i have changed to unique id in HTML but still it shows null